# Creating YSLD file on the geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, ysld

Couldn't find any information about creating YSLD file (for styling my map, because it easiest way to add everything, what I want). I am working on the Geoserver site, and as "style" I can create only sld file.
How/where is it possible to create YSLD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you [install the YSLD extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/ysld/installing.html)?

Once you have unpacked that zip file in the WEB-INF/lib folder and restarted the container (tomcat or jetty), YSLD is available as a drop down choice in the new Styles page:

[image]